# TableHeaderView with UITextView not sized correctly by its UITableViewController when UITextView.isScrollEnabled = false

Tags: xcode, uitableview, autolayout, uitextview

I have a tableView with a tableHeaderView that is assigned through a nib file. This tableHeaderView contains a TextView (orange background) that is sized with a height constraint using `sizeThatFits`.

```
let textViewSize = titleView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: titleView.frame.size.width, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)))
    textViewHeightConstraint.constant = textViewSize.height
```

The constraints of this header view are setup to properly drive it’s height.

[image]

When the tableView sizes the frame for the tableHeaderView i am getting very strange results from the `headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting` when scrolling in the UITextView is no enabled.

```
if let headerView = tableView.tableHeaderView {
    let height = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
    var frame = headerView.frame
    frame.size.height = height

    if headerView.frame.height != height {
       headerView.frame = frame
       tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
       headerView.setNeedsLayout()
       headerView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }}
```

If scrolling in the textView is enabled the tableHeaderView scales as expected, but the textView is cutting off the top line.

[image]

If scrolling for the textView is disabled (desired setting) then the height for this headerView is calculated to be larger than the size required. The length of text seems to multiply this effect.

[image]

I should also add that the TextView is being assigned attributed text with various paragraph and line spacing options.

Any suggestions as to what could be going on are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my issue. I am still not sure why the above problems were occurring, but when I applied the header view in a storyboard (vs loading it in via a nib file and assigning it to `tableView.tableHeaderView` at runtime) all of my autolayout issues disappeared.

Still would like to know why it was mis-behaving and if there is a way to get my table header views to work through a xib files